# How can I assign an interface variable to a sub-interface variable?

Tags: java, interface, instance

I have these interfaces:

```
public interface Interface {   
    int functionOne(); 
}

public interface SubInterface extends Interface {
    String functionTwo();
}
```

and this class:

```
public class MyClass implements SubInterface {
...
}
```

Now here's the problem:

```
Interface a = new MyClass();
SubInterface b = a;
```

I'd like to assign the instance of MyClass which *a* is addressing to the variable *b*. I don't want to create an identical instance, just transfer the existing one's address from *a* to *b*, but if I do it like this, netbeans gives me an error about incompatible types. How do I do it?

Comment: You're not able to do this because an Interface isn't necessarily a SubInterface. The compiler doesn't know that it's actually a MyClass instance, so we know something it doesn't. In this instance you may safely cast the value of variable A to the correct type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your code will not compile because `a` is of type `Interface` and that cannot be assigned to a variable of type `SubInterface`. thus you'll need to do:

```
SubInterface b = (MyClass)a;
```

if you think about it; it makes complete sense as not every implementing type of `Interface`  implements `SubInterface`.

If you don't know the actual type of the implementing class then you can do:

```
SubInterface b = (SubInterface) a;
```

which is much safer.

Comment: Casting to `SubInterface` would be better, no need to assume more than that.

Comment: @NickL, in this case, there is no harm as we know `a` is actually of type `MyClass` but sure, i'll recommend the other solution aswell.

Comment: while the code might work fine now, the harm comes from the evolvability of the code. You can no longer safely change the implementation to another subclass of `SubInterface` (and the compiler will not help you when you do). There is really no reason to cast to `MyClass` in the first place, as it is upcasted to `SubInterface` right away. So the only thing this may cause is a potentially unnecessary `ClassCastException` in the future.